# How to mock an interface in Unit Testing in Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I am trying to create a Unit Test for the following method:

```
public List<CompanyUserDTO> findAllByUserUuidIn(final Set<UUID> userUuidList) {
        return companyUserRepository.findAllByUserUuidIn(userUuidList);
    }
```

This method returns a list of `CompanyUserDTO` that is interface. Here is the interface definition:

```
public interface CompanyUserDTO {
    UUID getUserUuid();

    UUID getCompanyUuid();

    String getCompanyName();

    default CompanyDTO getCompany() {
        return new CompanyDTO(getCompanyUuid(), getCompanyName());
    }
}
```

Here is ***CompanyDTO***:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CompanyDTO {
    private UUID uuid;
    private String name;

    public CompanyDTO(final Company company) {
        this.uuid = company.getUuid();
        this.name = company.getName();
    }
}
```

My Unit Test is as shown below:

```
@Test
public void test_findAllByUserUuidIn() {
    Set<UUID> userUuidList = new HashSet<>();
    userUuidList.add(UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"));
    userUuidList.add(UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002"));
    userUuidList.add(UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003"));

    // --> here I need a mock list of `CompanyUserDTO`
    List<CompanyUserDTO> companyUserDTOList = new ArrayList<>();

    when(companyUserRepository.findAllByUserUuidIn(userUuidList))
        .thenReturn(companyUserDTOList);

    List<CompanyUserDTO> result = companyUserService
        .findAllByUserUuidIn(userUuidList);

    assertEquals(companyUserDTOList, result);
}
```

**1.** So, how should I create a mock list of `CompanyUserDTO` in the test?

**2.** Is my unit test ok with this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You don't need a mock, just create the objects themselves (I guess that you have at least an implementation of the interface `CompanyUserDTO`).
2. Everything else is ok, although your method does not have that much logic to be tested.

---

Given that you don't have an implementation for `CompanyUserDTO` you might make usage of anonymous classes to avoid having an implementation per se but something just for testing purposes. You could do it as follows:

```java
@Test
public void test_findAllByUserUuidIn() {
    // Arrange
    Set<UUID> userUuidList = new HashSet<>();
    userUuidList.add(UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"));
    userUuidList.add(UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002"));
    userUuidList.add(UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003"));

    CompanyUserDTO companyUserDTO = new CompanyUserDTO() {
        @Override
        public UUID getUserUuid() {
            return UUID.randomUUID();
        }
        
        @Override
        public UUID getCompanyUuid() {
            return UUID.randomUUID();
        }

        @Override
        public String getCompanyName() {
            return "Company Name Test";
        }
    };
    List<CompanyUserDTO> companyUserDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
    companyUserDTOList.add(companyUserDTO);

    when(companyUserRepository.findAllByUserUuidIn(userUuidList))
        .thenReturn(companyUserDTOList);

    // Act
    List<CompanyUserDTO> result = companyUserService
        .findAllByUserUuidIn(userUuidList);

    // Assert
    assertEquals(companyUserDTOList, result);
}
```

---

If you prefer to avoid anonymous classes, then you need to create the following class in your `test` source package:

```java
public class CompanyUserDTOImpl implements CompanyUserDTO {
    @Override
    public UUID getUserUuid() {
        return UUID.randomUUID();
    }
    
    @Override
    public UUID getCompanyUuid() {
        return UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    @Override
    public String getCompanyName() {
        return "Company Name Test";
    }
};
```

And then your test would be something simpler:

```java
@Test
public void test_findAllByUserUuidIn() {
    // Arrange
    Set<UUID> userUuidList = new HashSet<>();
    userUuidList.add(UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001"));
    userUuidList.add(UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002"));
    userUuidList.add(UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003"));

    List<CompanyUserDTO> companyUserDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
    companyUserDTOList.add(new CompanyUserDTOImpl());

    when(companyUserRepository.findAllByUserUuidIn(userUuidList))
        .thenReturn(companyUserDTOList);

    // Act
    List<CompanyUserDTO> result = companyUserService
        .findAllByUserUuidIn(userUuidList);

    // Assert
    assertEquals(companyUserDTOList, result);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any concrete implementation for the interface `CompanyUserDTO`?

Comment: Not concrete implementation, just used for some mapping e.g. `.map(CompanyUserDTO::getCompanyUuid)`

Comment: Ok, but for that mapping you need to have an object that implements `CompanyUserDTO`, otherwise it will not work. So my question remains do you have any class implementing `CompanyUserDTO`?

Comment: I searched on the project by phrase of "implements CompanyUserDTO", but there is not any class or file.

Comment: Are you using any mapping library such as MapStruct for example?

Comment: Yes, but should I simply use `@Mock List<CompanyUserDTO> companyUserDTOList` and then use this `companyUserDTOList` in my Test method?

Comment: Then there is underneath an implementation of `CompanyUserDTO` generated by MapStruct or whatever mapping library you are using. You should create a bunch of those objects so that you don't mock things that you don't actually need to mock. I will add an example to my answer.

Comment: I am waiting for your answer. But, why should not I use mock as `@Mock List<CompanyUserDTO> companyUserDTOList` ? It seems to be easier, but not sure if it is a good idea?

Comment: Thanks for your help and answer. However, I cannot find the `CompanyUserDTOImpl` and for this reason why should not I use simply `@Mock List<CompanyUserDTO> companyUserDTOList` ? Why the implementation is so important that I force myself? Because by mocking, it seems to be much more easier to pass and check the result. Any idea?

Comment: Why mock something that shouldn't be mocked in the first place? What is the feature that you need to mock from `CompanyUserDTO`? Is it a special class that depends on others that creating a new object would be hard? No. That is why I am saying that you shouldn't mock it. Still, I will add an example with a mock.

Comment: But when I try to access the implementations of `CompanyUserDTO`, it shows that there is no implementation of it. So, in that case, what is the most proper way? I just use it to give and then check the result. So, what should I do?

Comment: Then mock it. I added a version with a mock, please check it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i is not related to my want, there seems to be no other option. And, is it bad approach for this scenario?

Comment: I answered that already. There must exist an implementation for the `CompanyUserDTO`. Either you need to create one or your mapping library will generate it for you, but it must exist. I guess that you are returning this in your Controllers right? If so, an implementation of the interface is needed so that it works. Having real objects that implement `CompanyUserDTO` in the test is the best approach.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. But I have really no idea how to us it. But, what about the `return new CompanyDTO(getCompanyUuid(), getCompanyName());` in `CompanyUserDTO` interface shown in my question? Can I use it?

Comment: I don't know. Is `CompanyDTO` a concrete class or does it have a concrete implementation in case of being an interface?

Comment: You did? Where?

Comment: I am so sorry, I mixed it with `CompanyUserDTO`. I added `CompanyDTO` just below it.

Comment: Ok, that is fine. I see no problem with your `default CompanyDTO getCompany()` method in this case.

Comment: SO, as a result could you please update your answer for **Having real objects that implement CompanyUserDTO in the test is the best approach.** ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it uses more than 20 lines of code. So, I am not sure if it is the most proper way. On the other hand, your in your example, the result parameter has an element in it, but my example with mocking `CompanyUserDTO`, it does not. So, your example seems better but I am not sure due to the extra codes. Any idea?

Comment: By the way, voted up ;)

Comment: My answer will not change, no matter how many times you ask it. Avoid mocking stuff that does not need to be mocked. If you could have a test with concrete `CompanyUserDTOs` you wouldn't you? Mocking is only relevant when having a concrete implementation would be simply too much work. Additionally, if you don't want to have those lines in the test itself you can extract it to a class of its own in your `test` package.

Comment: I've added that example to my answer. Please check it.

Comment: Marked as answer, thanks a lot for all of your kind and useful helps. On the other hand, I am wondering if I could use `CompanyUserDTO` via  `getCompany()` property, etc instead of creating `CompanyUserDTOImpl` ?

Comment: But `getCompany()` returns a `CompanyDTO` not a `CompanyUserDTO`.